# Microsoft SDK XRM GetProxy "NoURL"

Tags: c#, sdk, microsoft-dynamics, xrm

we are using this guide and stucked while GetProxy.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675404.aspx

It gives us this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.Security.MessageSecurityException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail.

And when we see the InnerException:

> {System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Authentication Failure NoURL}

We are using OnlineFederation AuthenticationProviderType for Office365 XRM.

How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Install the below package in your solution if you are working with MS CRM 2016

[Link to Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CrmSdk.Deployment/)

```
Install-Package Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreAssemblies
```